# Tamaño de div no se ajusta a contenido

Tags: html, css

Estoy teniendo problemas en que el tamaño del div no se adapta al contenido, el cual es dinámico. Como pueden ver el fondo del div es color gris (background:  #f3f2ef; )

Este es el código css:

```
  #ionContentHome{
    background:  #f3f2ef;  
    padding-top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando me refiero a que es dinámico es porque el contenido del div es:

```
< div id="ionContentHome">  
  <Elements /> 
</div>

const Elements = (props:{ arrangement: Array<any> , setVerEmail:any, setItem:any }) => {

  var arreglo=props.arrangement
  var i=0
  return (
      <div id="elementos">
        {props.arrangement.map((a) => {
          i=i+1
          //item, imagen personal, distancia, calificación, email, nombre, apellido, tipo
          return (<CardVistaVariosProveedores key={i} item={a[0]} personalImg={a[1]} distancia={a[2]} calificacion={a[3]} email={a[4]} nombre={a[5]} apellido={a[6]} tipo={a[7]} setVerEmail={props.setVerEmail} setItem={props.setItem} ></CardVistaVariosProveedores> ) 
        })
        }
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Con lo que has expuesto en la pregunta es imposible reproducir tu error.  Además compartes el css de un componente llamado #ionContentHome y en tu codigo solo hay un div #elementos. Por favor edita tu pregunta.

Comment: Editado, de la forma implementado

Comment: ¿Has probado utilizando el valor auto? `height: auto; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria así:

```
#ionContentHome{
    background:  #f3f2ef;  
    padding-top: 1px;
    max-width: 100%; que el valor maximo sea el 100% de su father container
    height: auto;  //auto
}
```

Los elementos HTML no son capaces de tener una dimensión vertical del 100% salvo con un display:flex como elemento contenedor y no funciona en todos los elementos del mismo.

Coméntame por favor si te ha funcionado así

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado.